# How to Read metrics from Spark cassandra connector(Table Writer's time taken to write)

Tags: java, cassandra, spark-streaming

I am using spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.1 version.

Need to find out time taken while reading/writing into cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra exposes lots of metrics via JMX: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html
You will then have access to some cassandra client request latency (read and write). In the case of Spark, you have to be cautious as spark write in batches to Cassandra.

The easiest way would be to use a cloud metrics provider, such as datadog, to collect those metrics for you that you can then inspect.

As an alternative, a common option is to collect the metrics using Prometheus, and visualizing it with Grafana. There are a few blog posts out there that should help you out.